# php redirect is not happening

Tags: php, redirect

I have a question..

```
function curPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL.'?app_not_found';
}
```

Through the function I am fetching the current URL ....
now I have two conditions

```
if($databaseAppVersion == $appVersionName)
    {
        //echo curPageURL();
        header('Location: '.curPageURL());
    }
    else 
    {
        $url ="www.google.com";
        //echo $url;
        header('Location: '.$url);
    }
```

when I am printing them the echo is happening but the problem is that the it does not redirection me to the intended page ...
on the first condition I want to redirect to the current page having a message 
i.e. localhost/test/index.php?app_not_found
but this is not happening

Comment: Just a little off topic,  but for https, your code will append :443 since you are only looking for implicit port 80

Comment: Have you looked in the error log? Is any code sending anything before the call to header('location')?

Comment: nopes .... you have seen my code

Comment: can you please tell me where is the bug

Comment: Why not just open the Developer Console in your Browser and search for the headers?

Comment: BTW you should always add an `exit;` or a `die()` after a `header()` call, because the script continues even after executing the `header()` function.

Answer (score 0):

if your page is like this:

```
<?php

function curPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL.'?app_not_found';
}

if($databaseAppVersion == $appVersionName)
    {
        //echo curPageURL();
        header('Location: '.curPageURL());
    }
    else 
    {
        $url ="www.google.com";
        //echo $url;
        header('Location: '.$url);
    }
```

I wouldn't expect anything other than redirects to www.google.com, since you are not setting `$databaseAppVersion` and `$appVersionName` anywhere

if you have any `echo` or `print` functions before your header call, redirecting won't work, since the headers are already sent. See [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php).

on a different note; your curPageURL() will not necessarily return what you expect:

if you give it http://www.example.com it will return http://www.example.com  https://www.example.com will return https://www.example.com:443 since you only check for port 80.

you can modify your code easily:

```
function curPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80" || ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != 443 && $_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on")) {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL.'?app_not_found';
}
```